How can we restrict a specific role assignment to service accounts in GCP Projects across the ORG?
GCP - IAM :  How can we restrict a specific role assignment to service accounts in GCP Projects across the ORG ?
This should only be applied for user created service accounts.

Add more details to your question. 1) For example, you specify user created service accounts. What does that mean in your context? 2) Why are you allowing users to create service accounts? That allows more problems that you are addressing.

As per this official document:
To restrict a specific role assignment to  user- service accounts  in GCP projects across the organization. You can use the organization policies and IAM conditions.
The Resource Manager provides constraints that can be used in organization policies to limit the usage of Identity and Access Management (IAM) service accounts.
IAM conditions in GCP allow you to create rules for role assignments. You can apply conditions to ensure that the role is granted only to user-created service accounts.
NOTE: Avoid granting owner and editor roles to that particular user created service account so that the service will have only minimal permissions.
Create a custom organization policy that restricts specific role assignments to only user created service accounts. While creating the policy set the constraint to allow only user created service accounts.
To learn more about using custom organization policies, see Creating and managing custom organization policies.

To restrict a specific IAM Role on custom service accounts across all GCP projects within a specific organization, you can leverage Organization Policies with custom constraints under IAM & Admin → Organization Policies.
Currently, this functionality is not available out of the box. However, you can implement it by creating a custom constraint, provided the resource supports it.
Reference: Custom - Constraints Supported Resources
Based on the reference documentation, the "iam.googleapis.com/AllowPolicy" resource type supports such customization, enabling you to allow or deny specific role assignments.
Here’s how you can define a custom constraint using a CEL expression to restrict the assignment of a specific role (e.g., roles/viewer) to service accounts:
resource_types: iam.googleapis.com/AllowPolicy
condition:
  expression: resource.binding.exists(binding, 
              RoleNameMatches(binding.role, ['roles/viewer']) && 
              binding.members.exists(member, MemberSubjectEndsWith(member, ['iam.gserviceaccount.com'])))
action_type: DENY

Explanation:

RoleNameMatches(binding.role, ['roles/viewer']): Ensures that the
constraint targets the roles/viewer role.

MemberSubjectEndsWith(member, ['iam.gserviceaccount.com']): Ensures the restriction applies only to service accounts (identified
by their domain).


When this constraint is enforced at the organizational level, it restricts the assignment of the viewer role to service accounts across all projects within the organization.
You can test this setup by enabling the constraint and verifying its behavior against role assignment attempts. Feel free to share your observations or issues encountered during implementation.
Note: Constraints offered are of the List or Boolean Type, and behavior is classified as retroactive and non-retroactive. Always try this out on a lower environment first.
